# Stack overflow at memcpy only with optimizations turned on and specific glibc version?

Tags: c, gcc, stack-overflow, glibc, memcpy

I have an application which segfaults only when compiled with `-O1` and only
with gcc 4.9.3 with `glibc 2.22-r4` from Gentoo (it works fine with gcc 4.9.2
and `glibc 2.19-18` from Debian). With `-O0` it works fine and with `-O2` it
hangs forever on `memcpy`. I don't think this is a bug on glibc or gcc, but I
cannot find what's wrong with my code.

The error seems to occur because of a stack overflow in `memcpy`.

```
...
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
memcpy (__dest=0x7ffff7f42010, __dest@entry=<error reading variable: DWARF-2 expression error: Loop detected (257).>, __src=0x7ffff7f91010, 
    __src@entry=<error reading variable: DWARF-2 expression error: Loop detected (257).>, __len=320000, 
    __len@entry=<error reading variable: DWARF-2 expression error: Loop detected (257).>) at /usr/include/bits/string3.h:53
53        return __builtin___memcpy_chk (__dest, __src, __len, __bos0 (__dest));
(gdb) where
#0  memcpy (__dest=0x7ffff7f42010, __dest@entry=<error reading variable: DWARF-2 expression error: Loop detected (257).>, __src=0x7ffff7f91010, 
    __src@entry=<error reading variable: DWARF-2 expression error: Loop detected (257).>, __len=320000, 
    __len@entry=<error reading variable: DWARF-2 expression error: Loop detected (257).>) at /usr/include/bits/string3.h:53
#1  0x0000000000401f04 in memcpy (__dest=<error reading variable: DWARF-2 expression error: Loop detected (257).>, 
    __src=<error reading variable: DWARF-2 expression error: Loop detected (257).>, 
    __len=<error reading variable: DWARF-2 expression error: Loop detected (257).>) at /usr/include/bits/string3.h:53
#2  0x0000000000401f04 in memcpy (__dest=<error reading variable: DWARF-2 expression error: Loop detected (257).>, 
    __src=<error reading variable: DWARF-2 expression error: Loop detected (257).>, 
    __len=<error reading variable: DWARF-2 expression error: Loop detected (257).>) at /usr/include/bits/string3.h:53
#3  0x0000000000401f04 in memcpy (__dest=<error reading variable: DWARF-2 expression error: Loop detected (257).>, 
    __src=<error reading variable: DWARF-2 expression error: Loop detected (257).>, 
    __len=<error reading variable: DWARF-2 expression error: Loop detected (257).>) at /usr/include/bits/string3.h:53
#4  0x0000000000401f04 in memcpy (__dest=<error reading variable: DWARF-2 expression error: Loop detected (257).>, 
    __src=<error reading variable: DWARF-2 expression error: Loop detected (257).>, 
    __len=<error reading variable: DWARF-2 expression error: Loop detected (257).>) at /usr/include/bits/string3.h:53
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
...
```

valgrind:

```
...
==2566== Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801ff8
==2566== 
==2566== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==2566==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFE801FF8
==2566==    at 0x401EFF: memcpy (string3.h:53)
==2566==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==2566==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==2566==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==2566==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==2566==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==2566== Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801ff0
==2566== 
==2566== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==2566==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFE801FF0
==2566==    at 0x4A246B0: _vgnU_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:58)
==2566==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==2566==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==2566==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==2566==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==2566==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
...
```

Adding a few breakpoints here and there I was unable to pinpoint what was
causing the error, but since I only call `memcpy` at one place I assume it's
coming from there:

```
/* Copy the surface b into surface a, both w x h */                             
static inline void                                                              
copy(double *a, double const *b, uint64_t w, uint64_t h)                           
{                                                                               
  memcpy(a, b, (size_t)(w * h) * sizeof(*a));                                   
}
```

This is first called here:

```
double *surface = init(args.input[0], &w, &h);                                
if (!surface) {                                                               
  LOG_CRITICAL("%d: %s\n", __LINE__, strerror(errno));                        
  goto main_return;                                                           
}                                                                             
double *osurface = malloc((size_t)(w * h) * sizeof(*osurface));               
if (!osurface) {                                                              
  LOG_CRITICAL("%d: %s\n", __LINE__, strerror(errno));                        
  goto main_surface;                                                          
}                                                                             
copy(osurface, surface, w, h);
```

And the program doesn't seem to run past that `copy`.

I have checked with gdb and both `surface` and `osurface` are successfully
allocated with the same size. The code for init:

```
/*                                                                              
 * Read a .pgm-like file with the initial state of the plate into a surface     
 * (array of doubles), dynamically allocated to the size of the image and       
 * returned on success. On error, nothing is allocated and NULL is returned.    
 * The error is registered to stderr. The size of the image is read into w,h.   
 * On error, this size may or may not be read into the vars.                    
 */  
static double *                                                                 
init(char const *filename, uint64_t *w, uint64_t *h)                              
{                                                                               
  double *ans = NULL;                                                           
  FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");                                               
  if (!f) {                                                                     
    LOG_ERROR("Could not open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));            
    goto init_return;                                                           
  }                                                                             
  char mnumber[3] = { '\0' };                                                   
  uint64_t ignore;                                                              
  int rc = fscanf(f, " %2s %"SCNu64" %"SCNu64" %"SCNu64" ", mnumber, w, h,      
      &ignore);                                                                 
  if (rc != 4) {                                                                
    LOG_ERROR("%s: Could not read header: %s\n", filename, ferror(f) ?          
       strerror(errno) : "EOF");                                                
    goto init_fopen;                                                            
  }                                                                             
  if (strcmp(mnumber, IN_MNUMBER)) {                                            
    LOG_ERROR("%s: Wrong magic number: %s. Expected "IN_MNUMBER"\n",            
        filename, mnumber);                                                     
    goto init_fopen;                                                            
  }                                                                             
  ans = malloc((size_t)(*w * *h) * sizeof(*ans));                               
  if (!ans) {                                                                   
    LOG_ERROR("%d: %s\n", __LINE__, strerror(errno));                           
    goto init_fopen;                                                            
  }                                                                             
  for (uint64_t i = 0; i < *w * *h; i++)                                        
    if (fscanf(f, "%lf ", ans + i) != 1) {                                      
      LOG_ERROR("%s: Reading point %"PRIu64": %s\n", filename,                  
          i, ferror(f) ? strerror(errno) : "EOF");                              
      goto init_malloc;                                                         
    }                                                                           
  goto init_fopen;                                                              
init_malloc:                                                                    
  free(ans);                                                                    
  ans = NULL;                                                                   
init_fopen:                                                                     
  fclose(f);                                                                    
init_return:                                                                    
  return ans;                                                                   
}
```

It is worth mentioning that if I remove all code from `init` except the
`malloc` the program runs past the initial `memcpy` which seems to be
currently segfaulting (but segfaults later on at another `memcpy`).

The complete code with intrusctions and the necessary input files can be found
[here](http://inf.ufrgs.br/~afarah/files/heat.tar.xz).

Comment: This part of the code looks OK  (and good to see code with decent error checking, rare here..) .  Possibly there was heap corruption caused elsewhere in the code

Comment: Is the total memory usage of the program large? If so, and the OS uses lazy allocation, it could segfault.

Comment: @M.M Yes that's what I thought too (heap corruption elsewhere). The application is using just 458752 bytes at the point it segfaults (checked with `malloc_stats()` in gdb), and it should not use much more than that anyway.

Comment: 1) Recommended simplification:  Use `size_t` for `w,h` rather than `uint64_t`.  For array index using `uint64_t` has no benefit and will fail on `fscanf(f, "%lf ", ans + i)`.  2) What are the values of `w,h`?

Comment: @chux What do you mean "will fail on"? The value of both `w` and `h` is 200 for the input I tested.

Comment: A `uint64_t i` may have a range exceeding `size_t`, then `ans + i` is UB when `i > SIZE_MAX`.  `i` should be `size_t`.

Comment: @chux Ah, yes, I'm aware. I had some rationale about fixed type sizes but on second thought using `size_t` would indeed be best in that situation, thanks.

Comment: FYP : "application is using just 458752 bytes at the point it segfaults ...  and it should not use much more than that anyway"  Hmmm 200 * 200 *8 (sizeof double) * 2 allocations is 640,000 bytes.

Comment: @chux My mistake, I called `malloc_stats()` at the break point (set on the malloc). After the call returns `malloc_stats()` indicates `782336` bytes, which sounds about right. Valgrind shows 640,000 bytes leaked also (since it segfaults it never reaches the `free`). The thing is, Valgrind shows no heap corruption or any error up until it segfaults.